# Symfony2 intl only "en" supported

Tags: windows, symfony, locale, php-5.4, intl

I am working on windows machine with Wamp installed and PHP 5.4.3
Currently, I am developing a web application using Symfony2. While creating a form with the FormType, I needed to insert an inputfield that takes a float instead of a String. So, I used this code:

```
->add ( 'weight', 'number', array (
            'label' => 'register.weight',
            'widget_addon' => array (
                    'text' => 'kg',
                    'type' => 'append' 
            ) 
    ) )
```

when I click on the submit button, this exception appears:

> The Symfony\Component\Intl\NumberFormatter\NumberFormatter::getSymbol() is not implemented. Please install the "intl" extension for full localization capabilities.

So I activated the php_intl extension by deleting the corresponded ";" in my php.ini

The previous exception disappears and everything goes well.

However, when I change the "locale" parameter in the parameters.yml file from "en" to "fr", the following exception appears:

> Only the locale "en" is supported.
>   500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

I am stuck with this exception for 2 days now. I could use some help.

Comment: Do you have at least one 'fr' translation file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the PHP Extension intl is required but also the Symfony component:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Add it to composer and other locales should be supported too.